# Set root password in ubuntu kickstart

Tags: password, root, pxe, kickstart

I have a kickstart to set a password for root.

Currently, this is what it says in the preseed file:

```
rootpw --iscrypted $1$lK/0.tLv$XdsDIJ3KNU/Ta9r1Pr6Qt1
```

How do I generate a new hash for the root password?

Huge thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the current hash (looking at the `$1`), appears to be an MD5 hash.  If that's the case, try this:

`openssl passwd -1`

The canonical reference would be the man page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html

```
id identifies the encryption method used instead of DES and this
then determines how the rest of the password string is
interpreted.  The following values of id are supported:
ID  | Method
1   | MD5
2a | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some Linux distributions)
5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there a way to tell for sure that it's MD5?

Comment: Updated answer to include more context on how to determine hash algo.

Comment: Thank you so much!